# I've a trouble() with installing pandas 0.22 with "conda install" in my enviroment

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda, environment

I'm learning about pandas and when I create a enviroment with anaconda with python 3.7 I dont getting to install the **`pandas version 0.22.0`**(that's a version of a courso that I'm doing) after that. I try create the 2 in the same time, but its doesnt work, the return is that conflict, but i don't know why conflit is. So, I tried create a enviroment using the Anaconda Navigator, and I get it, I get it create a environment, but it doest have a pandas installed, after all this, I tried to install the pandas handly on CMD into the enviroment and it's returning this code below...

```
(python_pandas) C:\Users\luanx>conda install pandas=0.22.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining wincertstore:  39%|############################################5                                                                      | 19/49 [00:53<00:49,  1.66s/it| Examining wheel:  43%|####################################################2                                                                     | 21/49 [01:19<01:42,  3.68s/i/
failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Package wheel conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
Package python conflicts for:
python=3.7
Package pip conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.7 -> pip
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.23'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
Package setuptools conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
Package python-dateutil conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python-dateutil
Package msgpack-python conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
Package certifi conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2017.4.17']
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
Package wincertstore conflicts for:
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Supported version list](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/install.html#python-version-support) of Pandas version `0.22.0`:

> Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6.

You can create an environment with older version of Python in order to install this version of Pandas. For example, this would install it for Python 3.6

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6 pandas=0.22.0
```

You can more information about creating environments in [the Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: I would like to say, thank you! You're right, I do really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

pandas version 0.22.0 requires a python version from 3.5 to less than 3.6.0a0.
which is just like saying python 3.5 only. So you either need to use pandas 0.24.0 or greater or downgrade to python 3.5.

```
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
pandas=0.22.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
```

Comment: you could also try using ```conda install pandas=0.22.0 --no-deps``` but you will likely run into issues later on.

Comment: I would like to say, thank you to you too! Both right, I do really appreciate your help.